# Command line equivalent of cmake's find_package?

Tags: cmake

I'm debugging a cmake file which fails to find certain packages (using `find_package()`). What does `find_package()` actually do when it searches for packages, and can I simulate it with a command line call (without invoking cmake)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**1. What find_package does:**

From the [documentation of find_package()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html):

> CMake searches for a file called Find.cmake in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH followed by the CMake installation. If the file is found, it is read and processed by CMake.

On Linux, the default scripts usually are located here:

```
ls /usr/share/cmake*/Modules/Find*.cmake
```

**2. How to use find_package on the command-line:**

```
# cmake --find-package -DNAME=Boost -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=EXIST
Boost found

# cmake --find-package -DNAME=Boost -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=COMPILE
-I/usr/include

# cmake --find-package -DNAME=Boost -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=C -DMODE=LINK
   -rdynamic
```

Comment: According to `man cmake`, this "should not be used in new projects".  
But you can use something like `pkg-config aruco --modversion`

Comment: If you want to know where the -DMODE=EXIST finds the installed module, append "-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON"  to the command.