# How to get CMake variable of package in shellscript

Tags: shell, cmake

I want to find the `Qt5WaylandClient_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable which is set by the Qt5WaylandClient package. How can I get it from the shell (dash)? Something like this:

```
cmake -find_package(Qt5WaylandClient) -get_variable Qt5WaylandClient_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
```

or

```
cmake -file path/to/my/CMakeLists.txt -get_variable Qt5WaylandClient_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
```

Answer (score 3):

CMake does have a `--find-package` command line option, but it is not well supported, nor well-documented. There is an answer describing its functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863366/command-line-equivalent-of-cmakes-find-package), but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Initially, it appears you could just run `cmake` in script mode, using `-P`, on a CMake file containing your `find_package(Qt5WaylandCleint)` command and print its variables to the console.

```
cmake -P MyFindQt5WaylandClient.cmake
```

However, running `find_package()` outside the confines of a CMake project does not work. It yields several errors because CMake doesn't know anything about the system or your target language. So, you must create a minimal CMake project, then run `find_package()`. Something like this CMakeLists.txt file should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MyProj)

find_package(Qt5WaylandClient REQUIRED)
# Print the desired variable.
message("${Qt5WaylandClient_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

You can then run `cmake` from the command line, and this will print the `Qt5WaylandClient_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable to the console. You can use the `-S` and `-B` command line [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) to specify the CMake source and binary directories, respectively.

```
cmake -S . -B build
```